# Please move these comments to a chat room

Tags: support, chat, comments, moderator-tools

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38439/472) has more than 20 comments, and they're old enough that the mod ability to move long comment threads to chat does not work.  I think the comments here are worth keeping in some form, but having that many comments on the main site is not good.  In this case, there are almost as many deleted comments as intact ones.

I tried to, err, bend the mod tools to my will to summon the "move to chat" option, but to no avail.  In [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93444/provide-a-tool-for-moderators-to-migrate-comments-to-chat/237976#comment780398_237976), Shog advised somebody else who wanted to move a comment thread to chat to post on his site's meta.  So I'm doing that here.  Could somebody on the community team move these comments to a chat room (and link it)?

If anybody thinks these should be handled some other way, please speak up.

Comment: You can copy paste them. It's annoying.

Comment: I could (which would be a pain, and they'd all show up attached to my name), but I'm hoping that Shog's comment means that it's possible to invoke the code that does the mod move through means other than the unavailable mod interface.  It would be great if that tool were available via the mod menu so we could do it at will.